# Re-assemble dataframe by index

Tags: r, dataframe

What I'm trying to do is getting a dataframe where the repeated rows in the first column act as an index to copy the corresponding rows of other columns. I know this sound messy, and my inability to accurately state the issue is one of the reasons I'm having so many problems with this.
I'll provide a reproducible example below.

```
structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L), .Label = c("2016-01", "2016-02", "2016-03", "2016-04", 
"2016-05", "2016-06", "2016-07", "2016-08", "2016-09", "2016-10", 
"2016-11", "2016-12", "2017-01", "2017-02", "2017-03", "2017-04", 
"2017-05"), class = "factor"), Var2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), .Label = c("B2B", "B2C", "B2K"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(5L, 
13L, 8L, 13L, 36L, 5L, 18L, 1L, 12L, 24L, 22L, 6L, 24L, 15L, 
11L, 26L, 1L, 338L, 285L, 291L, 232L, 142L, 42L, 92L, 9L, 46L, 
34L, 45L, 35L, 30L, 31L, 36L, 56L, 9L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
7L, 0L, 13L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L)), .Names = c("Var1", 
"Var2", "Freq"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -51L
))
```

basically what I want is:

- On Var1 no repeated dates
- On the row where the date is repeated, take the value of Var2 and Freq and copy them in two new columns to the index of the unique date
- This must be done for every distinct level of Var2

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what your trying to explain is a dcast. Does this end up how you want it?

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(x,Var1~Var2,value.var="Freq")
```

Answer (score 1):

A `base R` option would be

```
xtabs(Freq~Var1 + Var2, df1)
```